# Using a siamese model to obtain an embedding by cutting off one half?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I used Keras to build a Siamese network using the coding format of one of the questions posted ([please see code sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323567/siamese-neural-network-with-two-pre-trained-resnet-50-strange-behavior-while-t)). To explain this briefly, I built a Siamese network using the pretrained efficient net so that each copy of the network produces a dense layer which then get combined into into a L1-similarity output.

However, during prediction time, I only want to obtain the dense output of one of the layers (as an embedding).  I plan on using a variety of unsupervised learning methods (including KNN) on these outputs.

During prediction, how can I ask keras to run only one copy of my network graph using a single input? Can I extract only a part of the NN graph? I don't want to have to always generate pairs of images or run the cost of running 2 images when I only need one output.

Comment: Have you identify the specific layer that you want to use as embeddings? And also ( from what I understood from your question), why do you have a siamese network if you only want to run a copy of the network? Why dont you just have a single model (efficient net) and use it  as feature extractor? @Merry

Answer (score 0):

Let me just make sure that I understand your question and context. You are using a Siamese network (efficient net) and you want to generate embeddings for your input images.

From the image below, you only want to save the image encodings for one the ConvNets?

[image]

If that is the case, I dont really see the point of building a Siamese network at all. Just go for a single ConvNet (using efficient net). Because if you use the Siamese network model, it will always ask you to make image pairs.

If you go for only a single ConvNet model, and you identify the layer which you want to use to get the embeddings, then you can use the `tf.keras.backend.function` like this:

```
get_layer_output = tf.keras.backend.function([fine_tuned_model.layers[0].input],[fine_tuned_model.layers[-2].output])
```

Which then, for the predict, you can call it like this:

```
features = get_layer_output([x])[0]
```

Comment: The reason I am using a siamese network is because I want to fine tune the embedding to recognize  images of the same "item" in my dataset which is quite specific. However, there's only 2-4 images in many of the groups so fine tuning using classification didn't seem suitable. What you showed me is correct - during prediction, I want to input image 1 and get the h(image1) - since this doesn't rely on the other half, theoretically, it should be possible to get this - I am just unsure if this is possible with Keras.

Comment: So you are using  a one-shot learning approach. I dont think it is possible to overcome or not form pairs of images, since you are using a siamese network. However, with the option I give (using tf.keras.backend.function), you can easily get the output from that layer. You only need to specify it.